# IOS: how do i prevent UIViewController dismission?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, dismiss

I have a wizard inside some UIViewControllers in a UINavigationController and UITabBar; wizard step must be executed in sequence and, if the user tries to push the back button or chooses other tab items, i must trap the event and show a message like 'Do you really want to stop the wizard (yes/no)?' . 
Which is the event that i must capture for showing my alert?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like this is a UX problem which could be solved by taking a slightly different approach to the way your UI is structured.

This wizard sounds like a [modal process](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/interaction/modality/), as you want the user to either complete a task by following the given steps, or cancel. In this case, you should [present the `UINavigationController` modally](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:). This will mean that the user cannot interact with the tab bar whilst in your wizard, so solves one of your problems.

As far as the back button is concerned, if you don't want the user to be able to go back, I would [hide the back button](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/hidesBackButton) from the `UINavigationItem` of all `UIViewController`s that are presented in the `UINavigationController`, and provide a cancel button as the left or right `UIBarButtonItem`. If going back is only an issue from the first step, then you do not need to hide the back buttons at all.